# How to unsubscribe a contact from MobileConnect through a landing page?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

While sending out MobileConnect SMS messages we will be using a custom "From Name" instead of a From Number. This means that we cannot get STOP/Unsubscribe replies on our SMS messages. To address this, we plan to include a landing page URL that enables a single click unsubscribe for our contacts.

I need the contact to be unsubscribed from salesforce CRM (mobile opt-out field) and from MobileConnect for the Business unit they are added to.

I was able to setup the AMPscript to update the "Mobile Opt-Out" field in salesforce but I have no idea on how to unsubscribe the contact from MobileConnect. I can't really find any official documentation on it either.

Came across a few questions on stackexchange which suggest using UpdateData function on the _MobileAddress view. But here I can't seem to access the ContactKey value and instead only the ContactID is available.

Is there a way to get the ContactKey value in the _MobileAddress view ? Or is there a better way of unsubscribing contacts in mobileConnect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a year since you posted this question, hope you already got the solution. Hope this will help someone face the same problem.

Check this salesforce [article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000312828&type=1&mode=1)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to work with [QueueMO API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/using-the-mobileconnect-api.htm) on your web form to update the mobile number Keyword subscription in MobileConnect.

Or an easier, but more cumbersome way is to use AMPscript to store these contacts to a separate Data Extension and configure a MobileConnect [Import Definition](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_create_a_new_import_definition.htm&type=5), that would look up these Contacts and change the specific Keyword status / or Subscriber status.